# Audio import library that is not under the LGPL?

Tags: audio, lgpl

I've used ffmpeg but that was under the LGPL. I switched to sfml but the audio import library it uses also is under the LGPL. I want to statically link the library without having to use the LGPL license for my project. Are there any alternatives besides using a single format library?

Comment: Isn't there an exception for static linking in LGPL?

Comment: Let me explain what I'm doing a bit. I'm creating my own open source library which uses several other libraries. Most use zlib license, some use bsd, and only one uses lgpl. I want to use the zlib license for my project and I want to allow users of my library to link statically for commercial projects without needing to include license information, source code, or even acknowledging the use of all of those other libraries.

Comment: Ah OK, I see now. How'bout libFLAC? It's BSD.

Comment: I think libFLAC only loads FLAC format. I want a library that can at least load ogg, wav, and mp3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libaudiodecoder](https://github.com/asantoni/libaudiodecoder/) decodes MP3, M4A, and WAVE on Windows and Mac OS X (+ WMA on Windows). It's available under an MIT license, which allows for static linking in closed source projects.

As a bonus, it works by wrapping the native audio decoding APIs on each platform, so you don't have to ship any (possibly patented) decoders with your software.